# Adding variable to String URL

Tags: java, php, android

I modified my code like follows according to what i understood from a stack overflow question i found

```
private static final String url = "http://****/get_items.php?keyword=%1$s";
String searchKey = getIntent().getStringExtra("2");
        Final_url = String.format(url, searchKey);
```

when i print the Final_url like this

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"url = "+ Final_url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

the printed value is always

```
url = http://*****/get_items.php?keyword=null
```

Is There Something I'm Missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with:

```
"http://****/get_items.php?keyword=%s";
```

Comment: ah thanks , i modified as you suggested and removed this line of code
String searchKey = getIntent().getStringExtra("2");
and inserted my Value Directly into this line
Final_url = String.format(url, "myValue");

Comment: And are you sure that the value is not null?

Comment: Try putting this String searchKey = "SampleValue";, just to discard the value from the intent is null

Comment: somehow using the intent, the value becomes null

Comment: Great!. perhaps you can select my answer as the right answer :)

Comment: It's only logical to do so ;)